# Applescript / Javascript : click button with getElementsByClass

Tags: applescript, html, javascript, click

Here is the button I would like AppleScript to click :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" autofocus="" ng-click="ok()" tabindex="0">OK</button>
```

Here is my code :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    delay 3
    execute front window's tab 1 javascript "document.getElementsByClass('btn btn-primary')[0].click();"
end tell
```

However the script is returning a missing value and the button remain unpressed.

Any idea how can that be done?
cheers.

Comment: Browsers won’t let you trigger the `click` event via JavaScript. For details, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143157/990363.

Comment: Chrome ? Cause I have the same working with safari , but to be fair it's only working when the windows is focused

Comment: Possibly – different browser JavaScript security models are not really something I want to spend too much time thinking about, I have bad enough headaches as it is ;).

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClass` is not a function. `document.getElementsByClassName` is. Making that substitution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: sorry the issue was on my post but not on my script, but still not working for me